# How can we identify the modular curve $X_1(N)$ with $\textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}) \setminus \textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})/K_{\mathbb{R}}K_f$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-groups, modular-forms, adeles

Let $N$ be an integer, and let $\Gamma$ be the principal congruence subgroup of level $N$:

$$\Gamma = \{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) : a \equiv d \equiv 1 \pmod N; b \equiv c \equiv 0 \pmod{N}\}$$

Then $\Gamma$ acts on the upper half plane $\mathcal H = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \textrm{Re}(z) > 0 \}$.  The modular curve $X_1(N)$ is the space of orbits $\Gamma \setminus \mathcal H$.

The notes I'm reading (https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/miyake.pdf) talk about a "natural embedding"

$X_1(N) \rightarrow \textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}) \setminus \textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})/K_{\mathbb{R}}K_f$

[image]

What is this natural embedding?  By strong approximation, it is supposed to be a bijection.  What else is it besides a bijection?  A homeomorphism?  An isomorphism of $\Gamma$-sets?

Comment: Maybe you have hidden this fact in your comment, but what I am trying to understand is the *definition* of the embedding of $$\Gamma \setminus \mathcal H$$ into that set of double cosets.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a modular form $f \in M_k(\Gamma)$, for simplicity $ \Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and set $$F(\gamma)  = |\det(\gamma)|^{k/2} (ci+d)^{-k} f(\gamma \cdot i)$$ where $\gamma =  {\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}}) \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q}), \gamma\cdot i =\frac{ai+b}{ci+d}$.

Thus $F$ is a function $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathbb{C}$ which is : left $\Gamma$ invariant and left-right $GL_1(\mathbb{Q})$ invariant.

Then show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(\gamma_n)$ is well-defined when $\gamma_n$ converges in $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_v)$. For $v= \infty$ it is obvious. Also for $g  ={\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix}}\in SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ then $g \cdot i = i$ thus $F(\gamma g) = e^{-i k \theta}F(\gamma)$.
For $v = p$ use that $F$ is left $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ invariant.

Thus $F$ is now a function on each $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_v)$ which is : left $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_v)$ invariant (for $v = p, \mathcal{O}_v = \mathbb{Z}_p$, for $v = \infty, \mathcal{O}_v = \mathbb{Z}$) and left-right $GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_v)$ invariant and transforms as  $F(\gamma g) = e^{-i k \theta}F(\gamma)$ for $g \in SO_2$.

With the correct topology on $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q})$,  $F$ is now a function on it.

Say a points of $X_1(N)_\mathbb{Q}$ are of the form $\Gamma_1(N) \gamma SO_2(\mathbb{Q})\cdot i$ for some $ \gamma \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, it  maps to $A_\mathbb{Q}\Gamma_1(N) \gamma SO_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q})\cdot i$ thus to $A_\mathbb{Q}\Gamma_1(N) \gamma SO_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q})$.

For $\Gamma= \Gamma_1(N)$ a congruence subgroup, it works the same way except for the few $p| N$.

Or something like that.

Comment: What is $X_1(N)_{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: The modular curve as an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. But maybe it is better to use the algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @D_S I'm sure you can fill the gap to make things more clear and precise, so tell me if you see better ways to define $F(\gamma),\gamma \in GL_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q})$ and the rest. An important point to emphasis is that the adelization works because $f$ is modular, it doesn't work for arbitrary functions on $\mathcal{H}$